# Update Spring Bean Property Across Multiple Servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Here is my scenario:  I have a **Spring Bean** called *APIBean* which acts as an API client to a remote REST service.  This Bean contains a property called *hostName* which is the IP Address of the Remote Server.  This functions as the base URI when the *APIBean* client makes REST calls.  The initial value of this *hostName* property is pulled from **application.properties**.

The challenge I have is that the *hostName* property is subject to change.  I have a web form where a User will update the *hostName* property when its address changes.  This is pretty straightforward in a single instance environment, but my application is distributed in AWS and behind an Elastic Load Balancer.

So how should I go about applying this change to all other instances of this **Spring Boot** application?

I've looked at [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) which externalizes **application.properties** to a centralized Git repository.  It even includes a /refresh endpoint which you can hit with a POST request to update Beans annotated with **RefreshScope**. But this endpoint only refreshes the single instance you are accessing.  It does not affect any other distributed instance.

These frameworks are great and I feel the solution is close but I need a little help with the last mile.  This must be a common development issue with distributed applications.  How can we update a **Spring Bean** property across multiple servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Spring Cloud Bus:  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus.

Comment: That looks like it might do the trick.  I'll give that a spin and report back with my findings.  Thanks for the suggestion.